# Does deleting the auto generated duplicate comment affect the duplicate flag?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions, deleted-comments

I just flagged a question as a duplicate. Whilst finding the question someone else manually commented that same question. I only saw it when the page refreshed from sending the dupe flag.

So my comment should now be deleted because it's no longer needed. But as it was auto generated when I did the dupe flag will deleting it affect that?

Comment: No, deleting it [the comment] won't revoke the flag. To revoke a flag you have to use the flag dialogue window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The comment and flag are independent.

You could retract the flag, but the comment would remain there until deleted.

Or you could delete the comment and leave the flag standing.

While it generally makes sense to take care of both things (delete the auto comment when retracting a duple flag, and viceversa), there could conceivably be cases where you want to leave one of the two while removing/retracting the other one.

Comment: For instance I sometimes delete the comment because I already commented in some way that is more helpful for the poster than the automatic comment, and I would like to avoid confusion.